# Нормально ли я считаю кол-во материалов? MySQL

Tags: count, php, mysql

```
  $query = @mysql_query("SELECT * FROM notifications INNER JOIN users u1 ON u1.vk_id = notifications.from INNER JOIN users u2 ON u2.vk_id = notifications.to WHERE notifications.npoints > 0 AND notifications.history = 1 AND (notifications.to = $id OR notifications.from = $id) ORDER BY notifications.id DESC LIMIT 10");
  // количество материалов
  $count = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM notifications INNER JOIN users u1 ON u1.vk_id = notifications.from INNER JOIN users u2 ON u2.vk_id = notifications.to WHERE notifications.npoints > 0 AND notifications.history = 1 AND (notifications.to = $id OR notifications.from = $id)"));
```

$count, вот это. Правильно или быдлокод? Только не говорите, что надо было так:

```
$count = mysql_num_rows($query);
```

Ведь в $query LIMIT 5, и он будет показывать всегда 5, хотя материалов свыше 3-х млн.

Comment: Чем вас не устроил ответ на почти такой же другой ваш вопрос?  
http://hashcode.ru/questions/185551#185559

Comment: Тем, что тут LIMIT в запросе...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну так Вам дали же ответ (ссылка в комментарии).

> > $count = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM notifications INNER JOIN users u1 ON u1.vk_id = notifications.from INNER JOIN users u2 ON u2.vk_id = notifications.to WHERE notifications.npoints > 0 AND notifications.history = 1 AND (notifications.to = $id OR notifications.from = $id)"));

Вы получаете ВСЕ записи и находите их количество, что не есть хорошо.

Здесь есть несколько вариантов:

1) Плохой:

```
$query = @mysql_query("SELECT * FROM notifications INNER JOIN users u1 ON u1.vk_id = notifications.from INNER JOIN users u2 ON u2.vk_id = notifications.to WHERE notifications.npoints > 0 AND notifications.history = 1 AND (notifications.to = $id OR notifications.from = $id) ORDER BY notifications.id"); //обратите внимание - убрал лимит
$count = mysql_num_rows($query);
//а дальше из $query при помощи PHP получаем нужное количество записей
```

2) По сравнению с предыдущим вариантов лучше:

```
$query = @mysql_query("SELECT * FROM notifications INNER JOIN users u1 ON u1.vk_id = notifications.from INNER JOIN users u2 ON u2.vk_id = notifications.to WHERE notifications.npoints > 0 AND notifications.history = 1 AND (notifications.to = $id OR notifications.from = $id) ORDER BY notifications.id DESC LIMIT 10"); //лимит есть
$countRow = @mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(1) as `row_count` FROM notifications INNER JOIN users u1 ON u1.vk_id = notifications.from INNER JOIN users u2 ON u2.vk_id = notifications.to WHERE notifications.npoints > 0 AND notifications.history = 1 AND (notifications.to = $id OR notifications.from = $id) ORDER BY notifications.id DESC LIMIT 10");
$count = mysql_fetch_assoc($countRow);//$count['row_count'] - количество
```

Хотя здесь мне не нравится то, что мы делаем JOIN`ы

3), 4) и остальные - после ответа на пару вопросов:

Исхожу из того, что users.vk_id - это пользователь VK.

а) Что именно вы хотите получить в запросе? Может быть вы выполняете лишние действия? Либо тот же самый результат можно получить более легким способом?

На вскидку писал, возможны ошибки (в том числе утяжеляющие запрос))):

```
SELECT * FROM users
INNER JOIN notifications as notifications_from ON users.vk_id = notifications.from
INNER JOIN notifications as notifications_to ON users.vk_id = notifications.to AND notifications_from.id = notifications_to.id
WHERE
    users.vk_id = $id
    AND notifications_from.npoints > 0
    AND notifications_from.history = 1
ORDER BY notifications_from.id
DESC LIMIT 10
```

Отличие - таблица users - гораздо меньше таблицы notifications, поэтому join`ить к ней - легче.

б) В табличке notifications могут содержаться записи где notifications.from от пользователя VK, а notifications.to от пользователя другой соцсети (не VK)?

в) А вам вообще нужна табличка `users` (т.е. u1 и u2) в результатах запроса? Т.е. после выполнения запроса вы используете данные, хранящиеся в этой таблице?

г) А что такое users.vk_id? UID пользователя в VK? А другие соцсети есть? Я к тому, что вдруг окажется, что у троих разных людей users.vk_id = users.ok_id = users.fb_id? Тогда вы случайно отобразите чужую переписку. А Вам оно надо?

Comment: Посмотрел сейчас табличку в вашем [вопросе](http://hashcode.ru/questions/185841/%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-mysql-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B5) - это у вас PRIMARY KEY такой странный?

Боюсь в notification и users также все напутано, может сбросите (лучше отдельным вопросом) их структуру, чтобы можно было сразу по ней советы дать, а то боюсь на миллионе записей у вас куча тормозов непонятных будет...

Comment: И кстати, в том вопросе я почему-то не могу дать ответ - вместо ответа у меня расположен блок справа (со ссылками на схожие вопросы и т.д.) И комментировать больше не могу, даже комменты свои изменить (хотя ссылка на преобразование в ответ есть).

По тому вопросу - "Стоят индексы на vk_id и type" - это Вы про PRIMARY KEY? Надо индексы создавать отдельно (в том случае). А PRIMARY KEY на id надо повесить, а с остальных убрать

Comment: @BOPOH, я реально дурак :c JOIN'ы же в mysql_num_rows() не нужны. Правильно Вы говорите! А насчёт PRIMARY KEY, что именно не устраивает? Сейчас 5 млн записей в notifications и всё летает :)

Comment: запрос в ответе даст декартово произведение. т.е. будет работать верно только если было одно сообщение от одного юзера другому и от другого первому (смысла в этом мало). иначе записей будет NxM, где N количество сообщений от одного, M - количество сообщение от другого (в том числе N и M могут быть нулевыми и мы вообще ничего не получим).   
Нужен union и сортировка для их упорядочивания...

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, я и написал "На вскидку писал, возможны ошибки")) Сейчас сам увидел что не то.

Про union - думал об этом, но не ясна была цель запроса, потому для начала написал вопросы.

@ModaL, я писал про таблицу tasks - там в качестве первичного ключа до фига столбцов, хотя в данном случае достаточно было повесить ключ на id. А на остальные столбцы расставить индексы (только не переусердствовать, иначе может быть только хуже, хотя опять же - все от конкретной задачи зависит).

В том вопросе комментировать не могу, здесь - символы кончаются. См. следующий коммент

Comment: @Modal, PMA - это phpMyAdmin, вы скриншот из его же вывода делали.

Под рукой его (PMA) нет, поэтому на память - после выполнения запроса, над таблицей результатов (но ниже отображения запроса, если стоит его вывод) выводится время запроса. Хотя может быть оно выводится и в самом отображении запроса (т.е. там где PMA пишет 'SELECT ... FROM ... INNER JOIN ... WHERE ... и т.д.').

Вроде прямо так и пишет: "Время выполнения запроса: 0.002".

Либо попробуйте в консоли MySQL выполнить запрос. Тоже время увидите, только она (консоль) округляет сильно (вроде до десятых долей)

Answer (score 1):

Трудно представить какой лес в голове ТС.

- Если вам все таки нужно посчитать только количество записей, то зачем вы подключаете таблицу `users`. Можно конечно предположить что в таблице `notifications` есть безадресные записи (с пустыми `to` или `from`), но это не похоже на правду.
- Функцией `mysql_num_rows` целесообразно пользоваться только для определения существования (>0) или отсутствия (==0) записей.
- Язык запросов MySQL намного гибче, чем вам кажется, поэтому все операции с базой можно и нужно доверить серверу базы данных. Следовательно ошибочно будет получать >1k записей а потом скриптом считать их количество, когда можно получить одно число.

`$r=mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM notifications WHERE npoints > 0 AND history = 1 AND (to = $id OR from = $id)");
list($count)=mysql_fetch_array($r);`

Comment: @KaZaца, почему все проигнорировали LIMIT 10 :(